# Flutter: Stripe payment sheet does not appear

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

I copied this code from various pieces found on the internet. I followed Stripe's instructions for the integration and now I do not receive any errors:

- Use Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above
- Use Kotlin version 1.5.0 and above: [example](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/79b201a2e9b827196d6a97bb41e1d0e526632a5a/example/android/ .gradle#L2)
- Using a descendant of Theme.AppCompat for your activity: example, example night theme
- Using an up-to-date Android gradle build tools version: example and an up-to-date gradle version accordingly: example
- Using FlutterFragmentActivity instead of FlutterActivity in MainActivity.kt: example
  Rebuild the app, as the above changes don't update with hot reload.

However, I don't even see the Stripe payment sheet appear.
Do I have to set something on the Stripe dashboard?

Below is the Dart code:

```
_createPaymentIntent(String amount, String currency) async {
    try {
      //Request body
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
        'amount': amount,
        'currency': currency,
      };

      //Make post request to Stripe
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${dotenv.env['STRIPE_SECRET']}',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: body,
      );
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } catch (err) {
      throw Exception(err.toString());
    }
  }


  Future<void> makePayment(String? isTripRecuperato) async {
    try {
      //STEP 1: Create Payment Intent
      final paymentIntent = await _createPaymentIntent('20', 'EUR');
      print("dentro i pagamenti:");
      //STEP 2: Initialize Payment Sheet
      await Stripe.instance
          .initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(

            customFlow: true,
            merchantDisplayName: 'Drivehome',
            paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent['paymentIntent'], //Gotten from payment intent
            customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentIntent['ephemeralKey'],
            customerId: paymentIntent['customer'],

            //applePay: const PaymentSheetApplePay(
            //  merchantCountryCode: "IT",
            //),
            style: ThemeMode.dark,
          ))
          .then((value) async {
        //STEP 3: Display Payment sheet
        await displayPaymentSheet(isTripRecuperato);
      });

    } catch (err) {
      throw Exception(err);
    }
  }

  displayPaymentSheet(String? isTripRecuperato) async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((value) {
print("dentro il foglio ");
        if(isTripRecuperato == "true"){
          try{
            FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
                .child("ALL Ride Requests")
                .child(referenceRideRequestLastTrip.toString())
                .child("paymentStatus")
                .set("successful");
          }catch(e){print(e);}
        }else {
          try {
            FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
                .child("ALL Ride Requests")
                .child(referenceRideRequest.toString())
                .child("paymentStatus")
                .set("successful");
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        }

        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: const [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.check_circle,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    size: 100.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Text("Pagamento Effettuato!"),
                ],
              ),
            ));

        var paymentIntent = null;
      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        throw Exception(error);
      });
    } on StripeException catch (e) {
      print('Errore di pagamento ::::   ------> $e');
      AlertDialog(
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.cancel,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Text("Pagamento Fallito!"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to provide more details about your integration (screens, logs...).
Between, you can follow this complete sample about integrating flutter app:
https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/example

Comment: Thank you for your comment... how can I make the sheet pull page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheet not opening because in payment intent api, APi not provide Empheral key secret just comment empheral key secret and sheet opening started..

```
await Stripe.instance
          .initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(

            customFlow: true,
            merchantDisplayName: 'Drivehome',
            paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent['paymentIntent'], //Gotten from payment intent
         //   customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentIntent['ephemeralKey'],
            customerId: paymentIntent['customer'],

            //applePay: const PaymentSheetApplePay(
            //  merchantCountryCode: "IT",
            //),
            style: ThemeMode.dark,
          ))
```

If you need to provide Empheral key secret then call this api before payment intent was call...

cUrl: (Just paste this cUrl and you can call this api for customerEmpheral secret)

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/ephemeral_keys \
  -u sk_test_.....................................................: \
  -d "customer"="{{CUSTOMER_ID}}" \
  -H "Stripe-Version: {{API_VERSION}}"
```

Official Stripe Doc: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic#set-up-ephemeral-key-server-side

**Full code here:**

```
 Future<void> makePayment() async {
    try {
      paymentIntent = await createPaymentIntent('34', 'USD');
      log("paymentIntent:::::::::${paymentIntent}");
      //STEP 2: Initialize Payment Sheet
      await Stripe.instance
          .initPaymentSheet(
              paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
            // customFlow: true,
            merchantDisplayName: 'My Shop',
            customerId: paymentIntent['customer'],
            // customerEphemeralKeySecret: 'ephkey_1M...........',

            paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent['client_secret'],
          ))
          .then((value) {});

      //STEP 3: Display Payment sheet
      displayPaymentSheet();
    } catch (err) {
      throw Exception(err);
    }
  }

  displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then((value) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                  content: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: const [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.check_circle,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        size: 100.0,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      Text("Payment Successful!"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ));

        paymentIntent = {};
      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        throw Exception(error);
      });
    } on StripeException catch (e) {
      print('Error is:---> $e');
      AlertDialog(
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.cancel,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Text("Payment Failed"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('DErrrrrr$e');
    }
  }

  createPaymentIntent(String amount, String currency) async {
    print("In Price");
    final dio = Dio();

    try {
      print("In Try");

      var response = await dio.post("https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents",
          // url("https://api.stripe.com/v1/prices"),
          // queryParameters: {},
          options: Options(headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer sk_test_your_key_here',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          }),
          queryParameters: {'amount': calculateAmount(amount), 'currency': currency, 'customer': 'cus...', 'payment_method_types[]': 'card'});

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.data);

        print("Ram::::::::::::Success");
      } else {
        print(response.data);
      }
      return response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      print("In Try");

      print(e);
      print("Ram::::::::::::False");
    }
  }

  calculateAmount(String amount) {
    final calculatedAmout = (int.parse(amount)) * 100;
    return calculatedAmout.toString();
  }
```

Put your client_secret, customerId and etc..

That after call makePaument method on ButtonClick

```
TextButton(
              child: const Text('Make Payment'),
              onPressed: () async {
                await makePayment();
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Try commenting customerEphemeralKeySecret and sheet opening started please try first this. That after try to generate empheral key secret from api and passing into customerEphemeralKeySecret that after Stripe sheet starting opening..

Comment: If you have any issue then feel free to connect..

Comment: i remove customerEphemeralKeySecret but now catch me this error :  Exception: StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: No payment sheet has been initialized yet. You must call `initPaymentSheet` before `presentPaymentSheet`., message: No payment sheet has been initialized yet. You must call `initPaymentSheet` before `presentPaymentSheet`., stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null))

Comment: Try my full code Simone

Comment: After implementing code just try to delete app and restart your app

Comment: In Price
I/flutter (18712): In Try
I/flutter (18712): In Try
I/flutter (18712): DioError [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400.
I/flutter (18712): Ram::::::::::::False
 Exception: Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (18712): Receiver: null
E/flutter (18712): Tried calling: []("customer")
E/flutter (18712): #0      _MainScreenState.makePayment 
E/flutter (18712): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18712): #1 _MainScreenState.saveRideRequestInformation.<anonymous closure>

Comment: Can you change your STRIPE_SECRET??

Comment: And try to remove payment_method_types[] this parameter

Comment: Now catch :  I/flutter (24979): DioError [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400.
I/flutter (24979): Ram::::::::::::False
E/flutter (24979): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (24979): Receiver: null
E/flutter (24979): Tried calling: []("customer")
E/flutter (24979): #0      _MainScreenState.makePayment (package:users_drivehome_app/mainScreens/main_screen.dart:301:7)

Comment: Please change customerId too

Comment: In query parameter(Payment Intent APi)

Comment: Great Dhruvil now it appears ... what if I want it in full page or at least not in drop-down?

Comment: or barrierDismissible: false

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem on Android by replacing

```
paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent['paymentIntent'],
```

by

```
paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent['paymentIntentClientSecret'],
```